# How to track conditional jump warnings in C code using vgdb

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, valgrind

I am writing a code in C which operates on file, it parses the text pieces from the file input.txt, here it is

```
(
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is
an English-language pangram – a sentence that
contains all the letters of the alphabet. 
)
(
The phrase is commonly used for touch-typing
practice, testing typewriters and computer
keyboards, displaying examples of fonts,
)
(
The earliest known appearance of the phrase
was in The Boston Journal. In an article
titled "Current Notes" in the February 9.
)
```

main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "include/functions.h"

int
main (void)
{
  process_file("input.txt");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

functions.c:

```c
#include "include/functions.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
  The example of input.txt:

  (
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
  is an English-language pangram – a sentence that
  contains all the letters of the alphabet.
  )
  (
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
  is an English-language pangram – a sentence that
  contains all the letters of the alphabet.
  )

*/

static void
parse_parentheses(FILE *fp, void (*callback)(char *))
{
  char line[560];
  char text[560];
  int inside_parentheses = 0;

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
      if (inside_parentheses)
        {
          if (strstr(line, ")") != NULL)
            {
              inside_parentheses = 0;
              callback(text);
              memset(text, 0, sizeof(text));
            }
          else
            {
              strcat(text, line);
            }
        }
      else
        {
          if (strstr(line, "(") != NULL)
            {
              inside_parentheses = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void
print_text(char *text)
{
  printf("Extracted value: %s\n", text);
}

void
process_file (char *filename)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen (filename, "r");

  if (fp == NULL) 
    {
      perror ("Can't open the file.");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  parse_parentheses(fp, print_text);
  
  fclose (fp);
}
```

It compiles and prints text successfully, BUT
i used this command to check if there are any leaks

```bash
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=yes -s ./file-parser
```

and it complained about unconditional jumps, and uninitialized bytes.

I've tryed starting vgdb server to track what exactly causes these issues,

```bash
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 ./file-parser
$ gdb ./file-parser
(gdb) target remote | vgdb
```

but i dunno what to do, can you suggest what would you do track these bugs?

Comment: You're doing `callback(text);` before you initialize `text`.

Comment: Also `strcat(text, line);`

Comment: @Barmar Actually, `callback(text)` (`void callback(char *x){*x=0;}`) can initialize it itself. Thus no gcc warning.

Comment: @gulpr It can, but it doesn't. The callback he's using is `print_text()`, which prints the contents of `text`. If it's uninitialized, valgrind will warn.

Comment: wow, initializing the char array to empty fixed the issue, thanks

Comment: @Barmar then I am undeleting my answer :)

Comment: So was your question about how to fix your program, or how to use `vgdb` to find  the cause of problems like this in general?

Comment: my quiestion is about how to use vgdb to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
char text[560];
```

has automatic storage duration and it is not zeroed when not initialized.

You probably want:

```
char text[560] = "";
```